# Integrate $ \int\frac{x-1}{x^2\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int\frac{x-1}{x^2\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}dx $$

I am unable to begin this question. Please give some hints or solve it.

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Comment: Are these HW problems? You seem to have a recent trend of posting questions with no work on your part that request solutions.

Comment: @zahbaz I am solving some question papers. Those which I can't solve I ask them over here. This forum is for asking questions only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$2x^2-2x+1=2x^2\left(1-\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{2x^2}\right)$$

$$\dfrac{d\left(1-\dfrac1x+\dfrac1{2x^2}\right)}{dx}=?$$

Or  set $1/x=h$

Can you take it from here?